# Why does my RxJS Observable chain not re-execute upon subsequent emissions?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working with RxJS in an Angular service, and I've encountered a peculiar issue with one of my observable chains. Specifically, I have two observable chains that are intended to enrich a stream of notifications with user data. The first observable chain logs and maps the results correctly and can be triggered multiple times without issue. However, the second observable chain, which includes a `concatMap` operator to combine and enrich notifications with user data, only executes once and does not respond to subsequent emissions from the source observable.

Here's the observable chain that works as expected and allows for repeated executions:

```js
private enriched_sns$ = this.sn_results$.asObservable().pipe(
  tap((results) => console.log('%cResults', 'color: cyan', results)),
  concatMap((results) => {
    console.log('before', results);
    return results;
  }),
  tap((results) => console.log('after', results)),
  map((results) => results),
);
```

And here's the problematic observable chain that only runs once:

```js
private enriched_sns$ = this.sn_results$.asObservable().pipe(
  tap((results) => console.log('%cResults', 'color: cyan', results)),
  concatMap((results) => {
    console.log('before', results);
    const enrichedNotifications$ = zip(
      results.map((result: StreamNotificationResult) => {
        return this.read_user_data_service.readUserData(result.activities[0].actor.id).pipe(
          map((user) => {
            const enriched_notification: StreamEnrichedNotification = {
                user,
                notification: result,
            };
            return enriched_notification;
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
    // Combine the original results and the enriched notifications
    return combineLatest([of(results), enrichedNotifications$]);
  }),
  tap((results) => console.log('after', results)),
  map((results) => results),
);
```

I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm using `concatMap` or possibly how the observables are combined and returned, but I'm not sure why it's only executing once and not reacting to subsequent emissions from `this.sn_results$`.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can spot what might be causing this behavior? Any insights or suggestions on how to ensure the second observable chain reacts to every emission from the source observable would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the reason why `readUserData()` was not returning anything on the next emission is because I was using `combineLatest()` instead of `zip()`. After switching to `zip()`, I was able to receive the data on the second emission because `zip()` waits for all observables to complete before returning the result.

```
private enriched_sns$ = this.sn_results$.asObservable().pipe(
  tap((results) => console.log('%cResults', 'color: cyan', results)),
  concatMap((results) => {
    console.log('before', results);
    const enrichedNotifications$ = zip(
      results.map((result: StreamNotificationResult) => {
        return this.read_user_data_service.readUserData(result.activities[0].actor.id).pipe(
          map((user) => {
            const enriched_notification: StreamEnrichedNotification = {
                user,
                notification: result,
            };
            return enriched_notification;
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
    // Combine the original results and the enriched notifications
    return zip([of(results), enrichedNotifications$]); // Now it will wait for all observable to complete
  }),
  tap((results) => console.log('after', results)),
  map((results) => results),
);
```

Comment: `zip` does not "wait for all observables to complete before returning the result", but it waits for each observable nth emission before it emits its nth value whereas `combineLatest` emits each time any inner observable emits. If some inner observable completes before emitting nth value, zip completes after emitting nth-1, and `combineLatest` completes with the latest value from each observable. So the reason it "fixed" your case is that `enrichedNotifications$` does not complete after 1st emission so `combineLatest` does not complete as well, and `zip` completes because `of` emits only once.